# Angular 2 or 4, which life cycle hook is right?

Tags: angular

In my **ItemDetailComponent**

I have this following code:

```
item: Item;
param: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( (params: Params) => {
      this.param = params.id;
    });
    this.itemService.getItem(this.param).subscribe(
                      item => this.item = item,
                      err => console.error(err)
                      )
  }
```

and on my ItemService I have:

```
getItem(id: string) {
return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/items/${id}`)
                .map( (response: Response) => {
                  const temp = response.json().obj;
                  const item = new Item(temp.model, temp.description, temp.price, temp.type, temp.imagePath, temp.longDescription, temp._id);
                  return item;
                })
                .catch( (error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

}

So TLDR;  ***retrieve item from the database depending on the _id***

This works, but the problem is the HTML component, loads before I can retrieve the data. So I get this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImagePath' of undefined
```

So basically the HTML renders before the item gets retrieved - casts the error because **item** is still **undefined**. But then later works when **item** is retrieved from the database.

Is there a solution for this? Am I using the wrong life cycle hook? Even though it works - I feel like I can do better. Any suggestions/solutions?

**EDIT**: Thank you for all your answers, but I believe that Suren Srapyan's solution was the simplest to understand/follow and had no errors.

Comment: it is an async call @SeanUrgel you either need to put everything inside the first observable in a async way or make use of switch or flat map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each lifecycle hook your item can't be retrieved before DOM's ready. One solution can be to use `ngIf` directive to hide that part of the markup, until you get the desired data.

**For example**

```
<div ngIf="yourData">
   <p>{{ yourData.ImagePath }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        this.param = params.id;
        this.itemService.getItem(this.param).subscribe(
            item => this.item = item,
            err => console.error(err)
        )
    });

}
```

In the html template use like {`{item?.ImagePath}}` the safe operator `?`

Answer (score 0):

One of the other answers uses a subscription within a subscription which isn't really RxJS best practice. You would be better using the flatMap operator which 
transforms the items emitted by an Observable into Observables, then flattens the emissions from those into a single Observable.
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

```
item: Observable<Item>;
param: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.item = this.activatedRoute.params.flatMap((params: Params) => {
    this.param = params.id;
    return this.itemService.getItem(this.param)
  });
}
```

In your HTML you can then use the Async Pipe `{{ item | async }}` in your HTML which will handle the subscription and unsubscription of the item Observable. 
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe